# Screen compatible to all devices in flutter

Tags: flutter

How to Adjust the screen to all android devices screens in flutter. I have checked in stackoverflow but unfortunately i haven't got any satisfying answer.

Comment: Flutter will automatically adjust the screens based on the screen sizes, so you don't have to do anything except if you want to make different screens for different orientations or big devices.

Comment: @user2682025 yes, i want to make different screens for only portable orientation.

Comment: Then you may follow this tutorial to better understand it: https://medium.com/flutter-community/developing-for-multiple-screen-sizes-and-orientations-in-flutter-fragments-in-flutter-a4c51b849434

Comment: Sorry, not enough information

Comment: It would be nice if you could let us know, what effect exactly you're trying to achieve? Handling screen rotating, ratios.. ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some questions about responsive layouts, so i will give you some examples with MediaQuery:

With MediaQuery you can get the device screen width:

```
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
```

The height:

```
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
```

as well as the orientation:

```
    Orientation orientation = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;
```

and also various information about the device, and then, you can base the layout on orientation, size etc.

Here's an example:

```
                 Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait ?
                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.3 : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2.1,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                        elevation: 0.0,
                        color: Colors.green,
                        child: Text("CONTINUE", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                        onPressed: (){
                          //code of onPressed
                          );
                        }
                    ),
                  ),
```

You can use too Align, to define where the widget should be, Positioned, the properties of Column, Center etc.

One more example, using FittedBox to deal with texts:

```
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Material(
          child: SafeArea(
              child: Scaffold(
                  body: ListView(
                      children: <Widget>[
                      FittedBox(child: Text("Test"),),
                      FittedBox(child: Text("Flutter Flutter Flutter"),) 
                   ],
                 ),
              ),
            ),
         );
      }
```

The result:

Portrait:

[image: Result1]

Landscape:

[image: Result2]

Comment: If text size is 15.0 then how to write a mediaquery of that text size

Comment: For that, use Flexible, Expanded, or FittedBox.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, Flutter automatically sets the height and width depending on the device sizes wherever possible. Example - if you have use a list view having 100 items then some devices may show 5 items at a time and some may show 6 items. It is automatically done by Flutter.

The problem comes only when you specify an absolute value for height and/or width. Let's say you've a widget and you specify width as 450. Now, it may fit on the bigger screens but on the small screen (e.g. width 400 points)then you'll see pixel overflow error in the UI.

Now, to solve this problem, you can use MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/width as suggested by LGM.